# Java - Cannot find Symbol for Contstructor

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.*;

public class GrammerStack extends GrammerStructure implements StringStack { 
 private String structName; 
 private int cap;

public GrammerStack(String structureName, int limit){ 
 this.structName = structureName; 
 this.cap = limit; 
 System.out.println(structName+"["+cap+"]");
} 
public void GrammerStructure(String structureName){ 
 this.structName = structureName; 
}

//Empty overrides. 
public String[] asArray(){}; 
public String push(String item) throws FillException{}; 
public String pop() throws EmptyException{}; 
public boolean contains(String query){}; 
public void empty(){}; 
public double fillPercent(){};

public String getName(){ return structName; }

public void main(String args[]){ 
 GrammerStack("Stack1",3); 
}

}
```

When I run: javac GrammerStack.java
I get the following:

```
GrammerStack.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor GrammerStructure()
location: class GrammerStructure
   public GrammerStack(String structureName, int limit){
                                                                                                  ^
GrammerStack.java:41: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method GrammerStack(java.lang.String,int)
location: class GrammerStack
       GrammerStack("Stack1",3);
       ^
2 errors
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong here, my method is not mismatched to the name of the file, either. "Grammer" is correct in this case.

Any help?

Comment: Please provide code of `GrammerStructure`.

Comment: Please share your `GrammerStructure` class constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first problem, add `super(structureName);` as first line in constructor. I assume you have `public GrammerStructure(String name)` constructor defined in super class. If this is not the case, please share your constructor.

```
public GrammerStack(String structureName, int limit){
  super(structureName);
  this.structName = structureName; 
  this.cap = limit; 
  System.out.println(structName+"["+cap+"]");
}
```

For second problem, you are missing the keyword `new`. Change below:

```
public void main(String args[]){ 
          GrammerStack("Stack1",3); 
 }
```

with

```
 public void main(String args[]){ 
     new GrammerStack("Stack1",3); 
 }
```

or

```
 public void main(String args[]){ 
   GrammerStack grammerStack = new GrammerStack("Stack1",3); 
 }
```

Comment: I believe you have defined some constructor in your super class `GrammerStructure`. I assume it take `structureName` as parameter. if yes, add `super(structureName);` as first line in class constructor method `public GrammerStack(String structureName, int limit){ `. I updated the answer. If this not the case, then please share your constructors in `GrammerStructure` class.

Answer (score 0):

This error occured because in your super class constructor, you haven't defined the no argument or default constructor.

When you define a constructor with arguments in super class, you have to define the no argument constructor too for this specific reason: the compiler will not add default constructor for you.

child class will throw that error you just mentioned because in child class constructor a default `super()` call will be added by javac.

Comment: I tried adding:
public GrammerStack(){}; but that didn't dispose of the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.lang.*;

    public class GrammerStack extends GrammerStructure implements StringStack { 
     private String structName; 
     private int cap;
   public GrammerStructure() {
}

    public GrammerStack(String structureName, int limit){ 
     this.structName = structureName; 
     this.cap = limit; 
     System.out.println(structName+"["+cap+"]");
    } 
    public void GrammerStructure(String structureName){ 
     this.structName = structureName; 
    }

    //Empty overrides. 
    public String[] asArray(){}; 
    public String push(String item) throws FillException{}; 
    public String pop() throws EmptyException{}; 
    public boolean contains(String query){}; 
    public void empty(){}; 
    public double fillPercent(){};

    public String getName(){ return structName; }

    public void main(String args[]){ 
     GrammerStack("Stack1",3); 
    }

    }
```

Your are not define default constructor without argument.When you define a constructor with arguments in super class,you must have to define default constructor without argument

Comment: When I change the code to the following to include the super() it still gives me an error, but only on the one constructor that is empty. Without the super in the other two it still complains about them, but with the super those two aren't mentioned.

       public GrammerStack(){
       }
       public GrammerStack(String structureName){
           super(structureName);
       }
       public GrammerStack(String structureName, int limit) {
           super(structureName);
       }

Answer (score 0):

When you define constructors in super class and sub class, **there are some rules to follow:** -

- If you haven't defined any constructor in both the classes, then compiler will add a default one in both the classes.. So, you're OK.
- If you **have defined** a 0-arg constructor in super class, still you're OK. Because, from any constructor in your subclass, if you haven't invoked any super class constructor, Compiler will add a `super()` call automatically as the first statement of every sub class constructor. (**NOTE**: - **Compiler only adds `super` call to**  **0-arg constructor**)
- If you **haven't defined** a 0-arg constructor in your super class, but have a parameterized constructor, then you might be in problem, if you don't give an explicit call to that parameterized constructor from each of your sub class constructor..  This is because, Compiler only adds call to a 0-arg constructor, and you don't have one there..

So, the problem with your code is the `3rd one.`.

**To solve the issue: -**

- Either add a 0-arg constructor in your super class

  ```
  public GrammerStructure() {
  }
  ```
- Or, in each of your subclass constructor, add a `super` call to your parameterized superclass constructor..

  ```
  public GrammerStack(String structureName, int limit) {
      // Add a `super` with some parameters to match your parameterized 
      // super class constructor here.. 
      // It should be the first statement..
  }
  ```

**Secondly**: -

You instantiate a class by using `new` keyword with your constructor.. So, in your main method, you should change your invocation with this: -

```
public void main(String args[]){ 
     new GrammerStack("Stack1",3); 
}
```